# Ndef.get(tag) returns null

Tags: android, android-intent, tags, nfc, ndef

I have this code and I always get `Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag)` == `null`. I tried to get it differently but I always get `null` right there, in the same place. Has someone some idea that what I'm doing wrong?

```
private ImageView imgSearch;
private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        //nfc not support your device.
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_nfc_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    }
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    getTagInfo(intent);
}

private void getTagInfo(Intent intent) {
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef != null) {
            NdefMessage ndefMesg = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();
            if (ndefMesg != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, ndefMesg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />
```

and:

```
    <activity android:name=".activities.NFCActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the foreground dispatch system to get notified about new tags

```
mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
```

As you pass `null` as the intent filter and technology list arguments (last two arguments), your activity will be notified about just any tag while it is in the foreground. Consequently, in the method `getTagInfo()` (or actually `onNewIntent()`), you receive an `ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED` intent.

```
private void getTagInfo(Intent intent) {
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // this part is executed, hence, you received an ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED intent
    }
}
```

This means that the code in `getTagInfo()` will be executed regardless of the tag technologies supported by the tag. Therefore, if the tag does not support the `Ndef` tag technology, `Ndef.get(tag)` will return `null`.

You can get the list of technologies supported by a tag using:

```
String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
```

If a tag does not support the `Ndef` tag technology, this could mean that the tag is not yet configured to carry an NDEF payload and must first be initialized ("formatted") using the `NdefFormatable` technology.

```
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
if (ndef != null) {
    NdefMessage ndefMesg = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();
    if (ndefMesg != null) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
    if (ndefFormatable != null) {
        // initialize tag with new NDEF message
        try {
            ndefFormatable.connect();
            ndefFormatable.format(newNdefMessage);
        } finally {
            try {
                ndefFormatable.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the tag neither supports `Ndef` nor `NdefFormatable`, this means that the tag is not an NFC Forum tag and does not support carrying an NDEF payload at all.